# Is the language to describe regular expressions regular itself?

Tags: regex, context-free-grammar, regular-language, context-free-language

If we describe regular expressions with operators `*`, `|` and concatenation `.` (which we simply omit for clarity), and parenthesis `(`, `)` and some letters from some alphabet `Sigma`, then is the language that describes regular expressions itself regular? In my opinion no, because the fact that we have parenthesis means that no finite state machine can recognise the input, so it has to be a context free language.

**Note on off-topic-ness**

I stand by my position that this question is relevant to programming since I came up with it while thinking about coding up a regular expression recogniser. If someone wants to implement such a thing, then one will soon realise that you actually need a context-free parser to parse regular expressions and this question will answer this. Moreover, the answer and question are not 'very theoretic' since the topic of finite automata is considered year 1&2 undergraduate material so putting it in the Theoretical Computer Science Stackexchange will be an overkill.

Comment: I guess this question is not really on-topic, but it is an interesting point. Maybe it should be moved to programmers.stackexchange? Or theoretical computer science?

Comment: I think your question would be more appropriate on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [cs.se]

Comment: One could argue that stackoverflow is not the place for this. On the other hand, if someone wants to code up a regular expression recogniser then this question and the answer below will give him a good pointer on where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not regular. Consider that the language of balanced parenthesis alone is not even regular. The proof by contradiction using the pumping lemma for the language of balanced parenthesis also works for the language of regular expressions.

It is [Context Free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) though, and it is very easy to describe with a Context-free grammar:

```
S -> SS
S -> S|S
S -> S*
S -> (S)
S -> a
S -> b
S -> c
S -> ...     // Continue for all terminals in the alphabet, and
S -> epsilon // The empty string
```

Comment: ahhhh ***the pumping lemma***... It reminds me of sleepless nights back in college.